# How to reveal hidden rows with jquery?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, footable

I'm using [footable](http://themergency.com/footable/) (a jquery script for making tables responsive on mobiles, tablets etc) but i have a problem. Touching-Clicking on expand for every row is kind of unnecessary for my project.

Normally with this code it works:

```
 <table class="footable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-class="expand">
            First Name
          </th>
          <th>
            Last Name
          </th>
          <th data-hide="phone,tablet">
            Job Title
          </th>
          <th data-hide="phone,tablet">
            DOB
          </th>
          <th data-hide="phone">
            Status
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
```

> $(function() {
>         $('table').footable();
>       });

But How can i expand all rows as default ?

Example code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZEu2/)

Comment: If you want them all expanded, don't enable footable...

Comment: @Rake36 i suggest you to examine question again.

Comment: I mean like this http://prntscr.com/1fgtp2

Not like this: http://prntscr.com/1fgu1k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/nZEu2/2/

Add this one line of script `$('table tr').addClass('footable-detail-show');` after your footable call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('table').footable();
    });
    $('table tr').addClass('footable-detail-show');
});
```

Comment: very clever! i wasn't aware addclass

Comment: the question was a while ago but still any ideas about how to do this on new version of footable ?

http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/auto-expand-first-row-on-breakpoint.htm

Answer (score 2):

Simply apply the relative classes which is

```
class="footable-detail-show"
class="footable-row-detail"
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nZEu2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to fix your issue would be to add

```
class="footable-detail-show"
```

To every TR element you would like to show.

However, agreeing with the comments above, maybe footable isn't needed at all here.

Comment: and what could be needed ? do you know better solution for responsive longer tables without rewriting code ?

Answer (score 0):

In new footable version use :

```
$('table tr').addClass('footable-detail-show');
$('.footable-row-detail').css("display","table-row");
```

Don't forget to rebuild the table with :

```
$('table').trigger('footable_redraw');
```